# How to manually initialize the values for the weights?

Tags: python-2.7, neural-network, tensorflow

I would like to experiment the weights initialization recommended by Karpathy in his lecture notes,

> the recommended heuristic is to initialize each neuron's weight vector
>   as: w = np.random.randn(n) / sqrt(n), where n is the number of its
>   inputs

source: http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/#init

I'm beginner in python, and I don"t know how to implement this :/

```
weights = tf.Variable(??)
```

Please help? ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single value, use:

```
weights = tf.Variable(10)
```

For a vector with random values:

```
shape = [784, 625]
weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape, stddev=0.01)/tf.sqrt(n))
```

Please note that you need to sess.run to evaluate the variables.

Also, please check out other Random Tensors: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/constant_op.html#random-tensors

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I don't understand where is the `np.random.randn(n)` in the line of code you showed. I think I don't want to use `tf.random_normal` with a standard deviation argument, but manually set each weight of the weight matrix with `np.random.randn(n)`. Can this be achieved ?

Comment: I would use tf.random.X. You can replace np.random.randn(n) with tf.random, and do the same thing. Please check out https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/constant_op.html#random-tensors.

Comment: @Kalanit Just curious, what do you think `randn` does which is different from `random_normal`?

Comment: @AlexI Only that in `np.random.randn(n)`, `n` appears. In tf.random_normal(shape, stddev=0.01),  `n` doesn't appear. Plus, I have to decide for a value as standard deviation. Am I wrong somewhere? (again, I am very beginner, so any explanation to help me understand would be welcomed)

Comment: @Kalanit: `np.random.randn(shape)*0.01` is same as `tf.random_normal(shape, stddev=0.01)`.  randn produces numbers with stddev=1, but you can multiply to get any stdev you want.  Other than that, they are exactly the same.

Comment: Oh! didn't know that. That makes all very much clearer - thanks a lot @AlexI

Comment: A minor issue: the API changed its name to `tf.random.normal` in TF 2.x version.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 10
init_x = np.random.randn(n)
x = tf.Variable(init_x)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
print(sess.run(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it in the following way:

```
    self.w_full, self.b_full = [], []

    n_fc_layers = len(structure)
    structure.insert(0, self.n_inputs)

    with vs.variable_scope(self.scope):
        for lr_idx in range(n_fc_layers):
            n_in, n_out = structure[lr_idx], structure[lr_idx+1]
            self.w_full.append(
                vs.get_variable(
                   "FullWeights{}".format(lr_idx),
                    [n_in, n_out],
                    dtype=tf.float32,
                    initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(
                        minval=-tf.sqrt(tf.constant(6.0)/(n_in + n_out)),
                        maxval=tf.sqrt(tf.constant(6.0)/(n_in + n_out))
                    )
                )
            )

            self.b_full.append(
                vs.get_variable(
                    "FullBiases{}".format(lr_idx),
                    [n_out],
                    dtype=tf.float32,
                    initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0)
                )
            )
```

after

```
structure.insert(0, self.n_inputs)
```

you'll have [n_inputs, 1st FC layer size, 2nd FC layer size ... output layer size]